# Something similar to GNOME's AlternateTab on Unity?

Tags: unity, gnome, compiz

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04, and I unfortunately find the application switcher (launched by alt+tab) kind of confusing. I found the [AlternateTab Extension for GNOME](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/15/alternatetab/) and like the look of it, but was sad to find out that I apparently cannot use it in Unity.

Is there any way around this? Is there any alternatives? I've looked at the [CCSM](http://wiki.compiz.org/CCSM), but I like the look of AlternateTab better (it probably reminds me more of the Win7 I've just left).

Thanks.

EDIT: Here's how it looks like right now:

[image]

Comment: Is the super+w combination what you're looking for? ("super" is usually the key with Windows logo or equivalent.)

Comment: @pomsky Nope, sorry, I'd like to not use my mouse when changing between apps.

Comment: What about alt+key above tab?

Comment: Your `.gif` is cool but it doesn't look like any **Unity** I've used.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Well that sucks. All right, thanks for your help anyways.

Comment: @BobsonDugnutt I added a new section to the answer to ensure you are running **Unity**. It's only for 18.04 so far but when I reboot I'll put in 16.04. You should see something similar though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per request, I'll add an answer.

In 'CompizConfig Settings Manager', I chose 'Ubuntu Unity Plugin', and under 'Switcher' enabled 'Key to start the Switcher'. I gave me a prompt saying that it conflicted with the "old" application switcher, which was apparently turned on, and I simply chose to disable the old switcher.

Answer (score 2):

I looked at your link and honestly don't see how it is superior to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> in Unity:

[image: Alt Tab.gif]

After the initial <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> if you keep holding down the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and tap the the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key it cycles through Windows and those with two or more sub-windows lets you pick between them. I think this is superior to Windows 7 but perhaps I'm biased.

### Make sure you are running Unity

#### For Ubuntu 16.04 LTS:

```
$ grep "^Exec" /usr/share/xsessions/*
/usr/share/xsessions/gnome.desktop:Exec=gnome-session --session=gnome
/usr/share/xsessions/ubuntu.desktop:Exec=gnome-session --session=ubuntu
```

#### For Ubuntu 18.04 LTS:

```
$ grep "^Exec" /usr/share/xsessions/*
/usr/share/xsessions/gnome.desktop:Exec=gnome-session
/usr/share/xsessions/gnome-xorg.desktop:Exec=gnome-session
/usr/share/xsessions/ubuntu-communitheme-snap.desktop:Exec=env GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=ubuntu-communitheme /snap/communitheme/current/session
/usr/share/xsessions/ubuntu.desktop:Exec=env GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=ubuntu gnome-session --session=ubuntu
/usr/share/xsessions/unity.desktop:Exec=/usr/lib/gnome-session/run-systemd-session unity-session.target
```

Notice the last line (far right side) shows: `unity-session.target`

Comment: Your illustration does look very nice (exactly what I'm looking for), but it looks nothing like mine. Mine consists of three panes which the windows cycles through.

Comment: @BobsonDugnutt Then that's possible using `Windows Key`+`R`+`W` and then using arrow keys or mouse to select which full window to pick from.

Comment: How can I configure my alt+tab to look like yours? What's the reason for the diffrenece? Are you using something newer than 16.04? You don't need the +R btw.

Comment: @BobsonDugnutt The `.gif` was generated with 16.04. I just rebooted with 18.04 upgraded from a cloned image of 16.04 and Alt+Tab works the same way. You are right in 18.04 the +R isn't needed but it is in 16.04. I'm using Unity desktop in both 16.04 and 18.04

Comment: Do you know why it looks differently for me then?

Comment: @BobsonDugnutt I upgraded my 16.04 on a test partition. Perhaps you can use `peek` to capture what your Alt-Tab looks like and post it into your question?

Comment: I have added a gif now.

Comment: After writing `grep "^Exec" /usr/share/xsessions/*`, the output is simply `Exec=gnome-session --session=ubuntu`.

Comment: Ah, I fixed it! In 'CompizConfig Settings Manager', I chose 'Ubuntu Unity Plugin', and under 'Switcher' enabled 'Key to start the Switcher'. I gave me a prompt saying that it conflicted with the "old" application switcher, which was apparently turned on, and I simply chose to disable the old switcher.